# Moodle persistent activity with PDF report at the end

Tags: pdf, report, persistent, moodle

I want to create a Moodle activity, sort of like a survey or quiz with many free text answers, and when the activity is done, the students should be able to print out their answers in a formatted PDF report.

I would also like if the students could go back and revise their answers and get a new report generated.

I would like to know which modules, plugins or what to use to achieve this. I would prefer to use the native modules, but is not an absolute constraint.

Comment: In case it was not obvious, I am referring to Moodle 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A hack to the quiz module would probably work best. You could add a PHP script to generate a PDF, probably to the results view. Have a look at the nonstandard certificate module to see how the pdf lib is being used to generate certificates there.